# grails (GGTS): can I automate copying of a class from target-eclipse to a deployment folder?

Tags: grails, web-deployment

I have a class in src/Java whose class file needs to be copied (or compiled) to a *classes* folder in my *externalConfig* folder from the *target-eclipse* folder - which is not visible in GGTS.

My specific requirement is that I need the class file to be available for Liquibase to invoke as a CustomTaskChange on a deployment platform.

Is there something I can code that would copy any class files in a specific package name into my target *classes* folder? Any solution that avoids having to go outside GGTS would be welcome. I have tried the Resouce perspective, but target-eclipse isn't shown.

Regards, John

Answer (score 1):

You can use the grails script to do execute by an event. You can use the command

```
 grails create-script scriptClassName....
```

or by naming convention, create a file called _Event.groovy under the /scripts directory. In this groovy file, create event methods. For example (this would be called when a war file is created:

In scripts/_Event.groovy

```
eventCreateWarStart = { warName, myDir ->
println 'EVENT CALLED!'

File libDir = new File("${myDir}/WEB-INF/lib/")
if (grailsEnv != "development") {
    libDir.eachFileMatch( ~/^(my_class_name).*\.class$/) { File classToCopy ->
        println "Put code to copy file ${classToCopy}"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I will try it out on my train journey in the morning. John

Comment: Many thanks. This worked a treat. In fact I found a simple way to copy the files, preserving the package folders, by using Antbuilder.

Comment: It would be nice if you accept the answer. It also helps with your percentage.